# Proper way of loading large amounts of image data

Tags: python, deep-learning

For a Deep Learning application I am building, I have a dataset of about 50k grayscale images, ranging from about 300*2k to 300*10k pixels. Loading all this data into memory is not possible, so I am looking for a proper way to handle reading in random batches of data. One extra complication with this is, I need to know the width of each image before building my Deep Learning model, to define different size-buckets within the data (for example: [2k-4k, 4k-6k, 6k-8k, 8k-10k].

Currently, I am working with a smaller dataset and just load each image from a png file, bucket them by size and start learning. When I want to scale up this is no longer possible.

To train the model, each batch of the data should be (ideally) fully random from a random bucket. A naive way of doing this would be saving the sizes of the images beforehand, and just loading each random batch when it is needed. However, this would result in a lot of extra loading of data and not very efficient memory management.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to handle this problem efficiently?

Cheers!

Comment: Did you find any solution to your question? If yes please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a preprocessing step, where you would either (a) physically move the images to folders associated with bucket and/or rename them, or (b) first scan through all images (headers only) to build the in-memory table of image filenames and their sizes/buckets, and then the random sampling step would be quite simple to implement.

Comment: I will try this to start with, I'm a bit afraid it will speed down the learning a lot if I have to load a batch of images between every pass though.

Comment: You only need to load image headers to get the sizes, the metadada

Comment: Of course, The preprocessing is not a problem. I mean loading 64 images (for example, witch a batch size of 64) between each pass through the network might slow the whole process down a lot.

Comment: Because loading is I/O-bound and learning is CPU-bound, maybe you can start prefetching the next batch in parallel to learning on the current batch.